# How to connect to SQL Server with R?

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc

I want to create a model in R using a connection to data stored in SQL Server datawarehouse.
I tried to use RevoScaleR library which returned

> package RevoScaleR is not available (for R version 3.4.1)

so, I edited the connection string (given on the code below) for ODBC library:

```
install.packages("RevoScaleR")
#require("RevoScaleR")

if (!require("RODBC"))
    install.packages("RODBC")

conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server=CZPHADDWH01/DEV; Database=DWH_Staging; trusted_connection=true")

sqlWait <- TRUE;
sqlConsoleOutput <- FALSE;
cc <- RxInSqlServer(connectionString = conn, wait = sqlWait)
rxSetComputeContext(cc)

train_query <- "SELECT TOP(10000) * FROM dim.Contract"
formula <- as.formula("Cosi ~ ContractID + ApprovedLoanAmount + ApprovedLoadDuration")
forest_model <- rxDForest(formula = formula,
                            data = train_query,
                            nTree = 20,
                            maxDepth = 32,
                            mTry = 3,
                            seed = 5,
                            verbose = 1,
                            reportProgress = 1)
rxDForest_model <- as.raw(serialize(forest_model, connection = conn))

lenght(rxDForest_model)
```

However:

> package 'RODBC' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>     C:\Users\sjirak\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpqa9iKN\downloaded_packages
>   Error in odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0}; Server=CZPHADDWH01/DEV; Database=DWH_Staging;
>   trusted_connection=true") :    could not find function
>   "odbcDriverConnect" In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc,
>   character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :    there is no
>   package called 'RODBC'
>   Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of the ODBC, I see the following functions

```
odbc-package 
dbConnect,OdbcDriver-method 
dbUnQuoteIdentifier 
odbc 
odbc-tables 
OdbcConnection 
odbcConnectionActions 
odbcConnectionIcon 
odbcDataType 
OdbcDriver 
odbcListColumns 
odbcListDataSources 
odbcListDrivers 
odbcListObjects 
odbcListObjectTypes 
odbcPreviewObject 
OdbcResult 
odbcSetTransactionIsolationLevel 
test_roundtrip
```

hence I dont see your function in this list. This could be the reason why...

Hence, check the documentation for the proper function.

Comment: I've went through the documentation, however with no success. There must been a change in the syntax recently, because no matter where I look, there're always the two syntaxes as I used.

Comment: What I see in the documentation is a function called... dbConnect(...), on page 3 of the document. Maybe you can try that one?